# This entity is not currently supported by force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, data-service

Does anyone know if case are supported by force:recordData ? 
If recordId is a case one then :

```
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/> <!--case record-->
<aura:attribute name="errorRecordData" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecordCmp"
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                layoutType=""
                fields="ID"
                mode="VIEW"
                targetRecord=""
                targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                targetError="{!v.errorRecordData}" 
                recordUpdated="{!c.handleCaseUpdated}"/>
{!v.errorRecordData}
```

displays :

> This entity is not currently supported by force:recordData.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far Case is not supported by force:recordData, but remember Lightning Data Service is still in beta. You can find the list of all supported entities [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm).

Comment: Yes thank you. One question though about this "beta" thing. If I love this feature and I want to use it for a customer. Do you recommend to use it ?  Could it be deprecated/broken in a future release ? Or juste improved :) ?

Comment: Well technically until it's GA Salesforce can't still remove it, but I think it's pretty unlikely to happen. It's supposed to be GA in Winter which is in September according to status.salesforce.com, so we'll soon know :)

Comment: by now, case is supported.

Answer (score 1):

And... here is the answer.. ! No 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm

> Lightning Data Service supports the following entities.
>
> - Account
> - AccountTeamMember
> - Asset
> - AssetRelationship
> - AssignedResource
> - AttachedContentNote
> - Campaign
> - CampaignMember
> - Contact
> - ContentWorkspace
> - Contract
> - ContractContactRole
> - CustomObjects
> - Entitlement
> - EnvironmentHubMember
> - LicensingRequest
> - MaintenanceAsset
> - MaintenancePlan
> - MarketingAction
> - MarketingResource
> - OperatingHours
> - ProcessInstanceHistory
> - Quote
> - ResourceAbsence
> - ServiceAppointment
> - ServiceResource
> - ServiceResourceSkill
> - ServiceTerritory
> - ServiceTerritoryMember
> - ServiceTerritoryLocation
> - SkillRequirement
> - SocialPost
> - Tenant
> - TimeSheet
> - TimeSheetEntry
> - TimeSlotShipment
> - UsageEntitlement
> - UsageEntitlementPeriod
> - WorkOrder
> - WorkOrderLineItem
> - WorkType

Comment: Wow.  I understand LDS is in beta, but I would have expected that the Case object, probably the most important object type for customer support applications, would have been one of the first objects supported.  Even custom objects are supported, but not Case?  I'm honestly floored by that.